# Perform Sql queries without statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So currently I'm able to perform mysql queries by simply doing

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connect, Error 

with connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="user",
        password="password",
    ) as connection:
        select_query = """
        SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
        """
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(select_query)
```

Is there a way to do this but without the "SQL"

Something like this pseudo code

```
table = Table("MY_TABLE")
return table.select_all()
```

Comment: You'll want an ORM. Sqlalchemy is a good choice. https://www.sqlalchemy.org/
The only caveat is that you'll have to define your entire schema ahead of time.

Comment: @Stephen. It's totally right if you use [Automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/extensions/automap.html)